# Interpretation of Poincare Map

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, chaos-theory

I have been trying to interpret a [Poincare Map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_map). The Hamiltonian for the system is

$$H=\frac{1}{4m}\left(p_r^2+p_z^2\right)+m\omega_\perp^2 r^2 +m\omega_z^2 z ^2+ \frac{q^2}{8\pi\epsilon_0\sqrt{r^2+z^2}}.$$

So, we have a 4D space and the Poincare Map would be a 2D projection of a 3D section (the system is conservative). $r$ and $z$ are actually $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and the $z$ coordinate respectively. So, I have fixed the Energy at a value $H_p$ ($H_p$ is in the units of $1\times 10^{-22}$ J) and then take a slicing at $p_z=0$. In the units that I am operating, the equilibrium point is (1,0,0,0) and the energy at this point is around $H=1$. This is the Map at very high energies i.e. energies which are far away from the equilibrium Energy. H=4000

[image]

I have a vectorized PDF too, but I don't see how I can upload it here.The issue i am facing is interpretation. For lower energies i.e. around 5, the figure is murkier, showing that there are there regions having Intial conditions which will show chaos. However, this one is like a 2nd grade illustration of Sun. What does lines emanating from a point. I remember the Star node that one gets in a special case a Jacobian Matrix, but is this it?
The MATLAB .fig file is https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzspU4hzroHuandDYUhWQkdBX0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding a picture with $r\in [-10,10]$ ?

Comment: The Picture has been edited.